# Reading data line by line from a text file

Tags: c++, text, stream

Each line of the text file has first name, last name, and a salary. Something along the lines of this:

> john doe 4000
>
> bob miller 9000

I want my program to take the first name, last name, and salary of each line and assign them to strings (or integers). I have tried this so far:

```
while (inFile){
    
    inFile >> firstName;
    inFile >> lastName;
    inFile >> grossPay;
    
    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << grossPay << endl;
}
```

When it outputs the names and the salary, the last line of the text file gets output twice by the program. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

After reading your last line, `inFile` is still in a valid state.

It's only *when it tries to read more* that your test would fail, but control has already entered the loop an additional time.

You want to test **after** reading.

```
while ( inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> grossPay ){
//      ^^ Now the test happens AFTER reading...
    cout << firstName << " " << lastName << " " << grossPay << endl;
}
```